# STS with custom username/password validator AND windows integrated authentication

Tags: claims-based-identity

Scenario A) User logs into a web application with a username and password. The username and password are validated against a WCF STS that generates a token that basically is the evidence / proof the user is who they say they are.

Scenario B) User is authenticated at the operating system level and logs into the web application with their Active Directory token, that is delegated to the WCF STS that generates a token that basically is the evidence / proof the user is who they say they are.

After Scenario A or B is completed, the user may request an operation that interacts with a WCF service that requires an STS token from the above STS service and is used to authorize the user to perform the requested operation.

Can I configure one STS service that can handle both the above scenarios and produce the same type of token as evidence that the STS trusts the user and is willing sign their token?

If yes, i need a sample. Urgent